# Why am I getting System.OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#

I have following code snippet in c#.

```
 var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(list[i].ToUpper());
            }
```

There is no compile time error in above code,but I am getting`System.OutOfMemoryException` exception at runtime?

Comment: A fine example of an infinite loop.  You can not loop on list.Count and increase the size of list and reasonably expect this loop to ever exit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List.Count` reevaluating each time you add an element.

So, you have 3 elements. After the first iteration of your for loop you will have `Count` == 4. So `i` never reach `Count` value (until integer overflow case, but out of memory happens earlier in your case).

You can write smth. like:

```
var listInUpperCase = list.Select(x => x.ToUpper())
                          .ToList();

list.AddRange(listInUpperCase);
```

Comment: ...which leads to an infinite loop. (+1)

Comment: @Matt, not quite infinite, as it turns out. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Every iteration of the loop adds an item. The loop's upper bounds (`list.Count`) increases. You keep looping. Eventually, you run out of memory.

To fix your issue, get the count beforehand.

```
int count = list.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop condition `list.Count` is evaluated on each iteration.
Since it grows by one each iteration(you add an element to that list) your code will loop endlessly until it finally runs out of memory.

If you want to replace each element by its uppercase equivalent you can use the following code:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i]=list[i].ToUpper();
}
// list contains {"A", "B", "C"}
```

If you really want to add to the list you can store the count in a local variable:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
int count=list.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    list[i]=list[i].ToUpper();
}
// list contains {"a", "b", "c", "A", "B", "C"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never ends, because Count is computed each iteration through the loop, and you are increasing Count by one each iteration through the loop. Since i started at 0, you will add items indefinitely until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your adding a new item to the list, thus i would never hit the list count and the max out whatever the max value for integer is.

Answer (score 1):

It's an infinite loop.  You keep adding elements to the list forever.  `i` starts at 0, and the list starts with 3 elements.  Each is increased by 1 in each iteration, so `i` will never catch up.  When the list inevitably consumes all the available memory, the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping your list till the end while adding items to it. So that end will never be reached. I think you meant to do:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = list[i].ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the for loop continues while `i < list.Count` which never happens, because you add a new item in each iteration. Use another list for upper-case strings, or take the count once before starting the loop:

```
int length = list.Count;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing counter value in loop body ! and it never ends.

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = list[i].ToUpper();
}
```